# Strange behavior in networking between 64bit and 32bit

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm having a strange behavior about my network setup. I have 2 laptops, one (Lenovo)  with Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and another (Acer) with Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit and a wireless router.

I'm connecting these 2 using the router but with a strange behavior. I can ping both machines, as well as the router, but when i try to access their shared folders (`\\computer_name\shared_folder`) the connection starts to fail and I need to reboot both machines to get it working again. But this only happens sometimes, sometimes it works.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with the architecture (64 vs 32 bit). It's probably something else.

Comment: It helps to post the error message.  Either the message or the event from Event Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that its not because of your Operating system and 32bit or 64 bit versions ,Please check your firewall and Security software.

- Make password for your user accounts on both laptop
- Disable firewall in your Internet security software or enable game mode
- In network sharing center,go to advanced sharing settings ,
     Turn on "Network discovery" and " Turn on password protected sharing" (So make sure these settings are same in your both laptops )

[image]

- In Network sharing center click your other computer name and enter password ,tick the check box "Remember my credentials"

[image]

> I am also having two computers connected via router one is
>   Lenovo(Windows 7) and other one HP ( Vista).